# Extract state abbreviation and zip code from strings

Tags: r, regex, text-extraction, zipcode

I want to extract state abbreviation (2 letters) and zip code (either 4 or 5 numbers) from the following string

```
    address <- "19800 Eagle River Road, Eagle River AK 99577
              907-481-1670
              230 Colonial Promenade Pkwy, Alabaster AL 35007
              205-620-0360
              360 Connecticut Avenue, Norwalk CT 06854
              860-409-0404
              2080 S Lincoln, Jerome ID 83338
              208-324-4333
              20175 Civic Center Dr, Augusta ME 4330
              207-623-8223
              830 Harvest Ln, Williston VT 5495
              802-878-5233
              "
```

For the zip code, I tried few methods that I found on here but it didn't work mainly because of the 5 number street address or zip codes that have only 4 numbers

```
    text <- readLines(textConnection(address))

    library(stringi)
    zip <- stri_extract_last_regex(text, "\\d{5}")
    zip

    library(qdapRegex)
    rm_zip3 <- rm_(pattern="(?<!\\d)\\d{5}(?!\\d)", extract = TRUE)
    zip <- rm_zip3(text)
    zip

    [1] "99577" "1670"  "35007" "0360"  "06854" "0404"  "83338" "4333"  "4330"  "8223"  "5495"  "5233"  NA
```

For the state abbreviation, I have no idea how to extract

Any help is appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Edit 1: Include phone numbers

Comment: You want to do it programatically or just by using regex ? I mean it can also be done by Notepad++

Comment: `states <- str_extract(text, "\\b[A-Z]+(?=\\s+\\d{5}$)")`

Comment: Thank you @Rahul. Both would be great. At least can you show me how to do it with Notepad++?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Thanks! I still got error with the last 2 lines `"AK" "AL" "CT" "ID" NA   NA`

Comment: @IloveCatandPython Modify the `{5}` to `{4,5}` like this: `states <- str_extract(text, "\\b[A-Z]+(?=\\s+\\d{5}$)")`

Comment: @degant it worked now. Can you help with extracting the zip code and provide it as an answer to my question? Thanks!

Comment: Btw there is an issue with your data - those zip codes are incorrect. `4330` is actually `04300`, the leading 0 must've been lost while retrieving the data. If you fix that issue, you should be able to use @WiktorStribiżew 's solution

Comment: @degant i realized that as well but that what I got from other people. I have no control on it :/

Comment: @K..pradeeep: Thank you! I got `data frame with 0 columns and 0 rows` (please note that I updated the address to include phone numbers as well)

Comment: @K..pradeeep: I copied & pasted yours into R and used both `address` and `text`. Results are the same. Can you make your comment as an answer so the format looks better?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Code to extract zip code:

```
zip <- str_extract(text, "\\d{5}")
```

Code to extract state code:

```
states <- str_extract(text, "\\b[A-Z]{2}(?=\\s+\\d{5}$)")
```

Code to extract phone numbers:

```
phone <- str_extract(text, "\\b\\d{3}-\\d{3}-\\d{4}\\b")
```

**NOTE:**  Looks like there's an issue with your data because the last 2 zip codes should be 5 characters long and not 4. `4330`  should actually be `04330`. If you don't have control over the data source, but know for sure that they are US codes you could pad 0's on the left as required. However since you are looking for a solution for 4 or 5 characters, you can use this:

Code to extract zip code (looks for space in front and newline at the back so that parts of a phone number or an address aren't picked)

```
zip <- str_extract(text, "(?<= )\\d{4,5}(?=\\n|$)")
```

Code to extract state code:

```
states <- str_extract(text, "\\b[A-Z]{2}(?=\\s+\\d{4,5}$)")
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/7Im0Mu/2

Comment: Thanks! I updated the address to include phone numbers as well. Can you modify your code accordingly? Also, looks like the `state` didn't work as intended `[1] "AK" NA   "AL" NA   "CT" NA   "ID" NA   "ME" NA   "VT" NA   NA`

Comment: Added code for phone number. I think you are getting extra `NA` every alternate line because now your phone number is on another line and `str_extract` tries to extract zip code for each line and isn't able to find any ZIP code on the 2nd line containing phone number

Comment: Sorry for not being clear! With the added phone numbers, the last 4 digits in them will also show up after extraction `[1] "99577" "1670"  "35007" "0360"  "06854" "0404"  "83338" "4333"  "4330"  "8223"  "5495"  "5233"  NA`

Comment: Sorry I thought I fixed that. I updated the code and demo link now, take a look. You'll also get the same problem here like `state` codes though, each alternate one will be `NA` due to the number of lines in your text

Answer (score 3):

I am using **address** as input not the text, see if it works for your case.

**Assumptions on regex:** Two capital letters followed by 4 or 5 numeric letters are for state and zip, The phone numbers are always on next line.

**Input**:

```
address <- "19800 Eagle River Road, Eagle River AK 99577
907-481-1670
230 Colonial Promenade Pkwy, Alabaster AL 35007
205-620-0360
360 Connecticut Avenue, Norwalk CT 06854
860-409-0404
2080 S Lincoln, Jerome ID 83338
208-324-4333
20175 Civic Center Dr, Augusta ME 4330
207-623-8223
830 Harvest Ln, Williston VT 5495
802-878-5233
"
```

I am using `stringr` library , you may choose any other to extract the information as you wish.

```
library(stringr)
df <- data.frame(do.call("rbind",strsplit(str_extract_all(address,"[A-Z][A-Z]\\s\\d{4,5}\\s\\d{3}-\\d{3}-\\d{4}")[[1]],split="\\s|\\n")))
names(df) <- c("state","Zip","Phone")
```

**EDIT**:

In case someone want to use text as input,

```
text <- readLines(textConnection(address))
text <- data.frame(text)
st_zip <- setNames(data.frame(str_extract_all(text$text,"[A-Z][A-Z]\\s\\d{4,5}",simplify = T)),"St_zip")
pin <- setNames(data.frame(str_extract_all(text$text,"\\d{3}-\\d{3}-\\d{4}",simplify = T)),"pin")
st_zip <- st_zip[st_zip$St_zip != "",]
df1 <- setNames(data.frame(do.call("rbind",strsplit(st_zip,split=' '))),c("State","Zip"))
pin <- pin[pin$pin != "",]
df2 <- data.frame(cbind(df1,pin))
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
    State   Zip    pin
1    AK 99577 907-481-1670
2    AL 35007 205-620-0360
3    CT 06854 860-409-0404
4    ID 83338 208-324-4333
5    ME  4330 207-623-8223
6    VT  5495 802-878-5233
```

Comment: Thank you! It works now. Is it possible to modify your code to work with reading text from file or at least work with `text` instead of `address`?

Comment: @IloveCatandPython see the edit, I hope this is helpful

Comment: Thanks @K..pradeeep! Much appreciated! If only I could choose more than one answer.

Answer (score 2):

> Thank you @Rahul. Both would be great. At least can you show me how to do it with Notepad++?
>
> ---

**Extraction using Notepad++**

1. Well first copy your whole data in a file.
2. Go to `Find` by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>. This will open search dialog box. Choose `Replace` tab search with regex `([A-Z]{2}\s*\d{4,5})$` and replace with `\n-\1-\n`. This will search for state abbreviation and ZIP code and place them in new line with `-` as prefix and suffix.

[image]

3. Now go to `Mark` tab. Check `Bookmark Line` checkbox then search with `-(.*?)-` and press `Mark All`. This will mark state abb and ZIP which are in newlines with `-`.

[image]

4. Now go to **Search `-->` Bookmark `-->` Remove Unmarked Lines**

[image: Result]

5. Finally search with `^-|-$` and replace with empty string.

[image]

---

**Update**

So now there will be phone numbers too ? In that case you only have to remove $ from regex in step 2. Regex to use will be `([A-Z]{2}\s*\d{4,5})`. Rest all steps will be same.

Comment: Thank you @Rahul! It didn't work for me [link](http://i.imgur.com/f5reJMz.png) (please note that I updated the address to include phone numbers as well)

Comment: @IloveCatandPython: So now there will be phone numbers too ? In that case you only have to remove `$` from regex in step 2. Regex to use will be `([A-Z]{2}\s*\d{4,5})`. Rest all steps will be same.

Comment: Notepad++ kept telling me `Find: Can't find the text "([A-Z]{2}\s*\d{4,5})"`. Do I need to install any plugin for it? TY

Comment: You have to search it in `Replace` tab and do the replacement accordingly. Please read the steps.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realized that you have to chose `Regular expression` in `Search Mode`

Comment: @IloveCatandPython: Oh . . Yea. That one too.

Comment: So far this is the only working solution but I'm still looking for an R solution as it more reproducible. But thank you very much for helping. I appreciate it!

Comment: @IloveCatandPython: If I knew R I would had tried. You are welcome.